# Recorrer posiciones de listas

Tags: c#, lista

Tengo una lista

```
List<List<string>> listaEncontradas = new List<List<string>>();
```

Donde dentro tengo otras listas.

1. En la primera lista tengo 38 posiciones que serían mis cabeceras.
2. En las listas restantes son los datos correspondientes a las cabeceras que aquí en estas
   nada más me cuentan como 37 posiciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en las listas restantes, a partir de la posición 22 de cada lista, quiero que se recorran una posición adelante, por ejemplo. Que en la posición 23 tenga el valor de la 22, en la posición 24, el valor de la 23 y así sucesivamente...

He estado intentado pero no me da.

```
int inicioPosicion = 22;
                foreach (List<string> lista in listaEncontradas.Skip(1))
                {
                    for (int i = inicioPosicion; i < lista.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        string temp = lista[i];
                        lista[i] = lista[i + 1];
                        lista[i + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
```

He estado utilizando este código pero la recorre para atrás en vez, de para adelante.

Comment: *quiero que se recorran una posición adelante*. ¿Que se muevan una posición hacia atrás querrás decir? ¿Y en qué falla tu código? Sería de ayuda si nos dieras un ejemplo de entrada y resultado esperado.

Comment: Sí, falla por qué en la posición que quiero en la '22', obtengo el valor que tengo en la posición que sigue, osea de la 23.  Y es al revés, que se muevan para adelante o no para atrás.

Comment: Y no es lo mismo que sacar la posición 22?? algo como `listaEncontradas.Remove(listaEncontradas[22]);` ?

Comment: No, no es lo mismo... no quiero eliminar

Answer (score 0):

El indice de cada lista se inicializa en cero `0`es decir que `lista[22]`corresponde al elemento 23 dentro de la lista, si quieres obtener los elementos a partir del número 22, deberías inicializar el indice en 21 `int inicioPosicion = 21;` así como se muestra a continuación.

```
int inicioPosicion = 21;

foreach (List<string> lista in listaEncontradas.Skip(1))
{
    for (int i = inicioPosicion; i < lista.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        string temp = lista[i];
        lista[i] = lista[i + 1];
        lista[i + 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: No es eso, si no que se come una antes de la posición 22. Te adjunto el [Enlace](https://imgur.com/a/9h7OTtx) de las 2 imágenes donde están el antes y después, de aplicar ese código.

Comment: Ya entiendo lo que te sucede, en la primera iteración, el valor de la posición 23 se asigna a la posición 22 y el de la 22 se asigna a la 23, en la segunda iteración el valor de la 24 se asigna a la 23 y el de la 23 (esta posición 23 era previamente la 22) se asigna a la 24, así sucederá hasta que la posición 22 antes de iniciar el laso, termine en la posición final, si te fijas en tu imagen, el valor `"No"` que estaba en la posición 22 antes de aplicar el código, ahora está en la posición final.

Comment: Pero esa es la única lógica posible, si intercambias **[22]** y [23], luego **[23]** y [24], luego **[24]** y [25] y así sucesivamente, la posición **[22]** inicial terminará estando al final, después de aplicar el código. Otro caso diferente seria en la primera iteración intercambiar  [22] y [23], en la segunda [24] y [25], en la tercera [26] y [27], pero esa seria una lógica totalmente diferente y por tanto el código debería ser otro, pero el problema planteado no especifica que sea eso lo que se desea.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución pero no se si sea la más optima y la mejor pero, inserto una nueva posición en la posición 22 y sí me recorre los demás datos.

```
 int inicioPosicion = 22;
 foreach (List<string> lista in listaEncontradas.Skip(1))
 {
   lista.Insert(inicioPosicion, "0");
 }
```